# how to remove unsafe block in Scan 0 member of Bitmap Data

Tags: c#

I want to change the my manager code. But, this code has the unsafe block code. I want to remove or change the unsafe code.

I tried to use the IntPtr by BitmapData.Scan0. But, I don't know how to write by this member to BitmapData.

```
            Bitmap btm = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            BitmapData btmdata = btm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly
                                                , PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* Pointer = (byte*)btmdata.Scan0.ToPointer();
                for (int i = 0; i < height * width; i++, Pointer++)
                {
                    *Pointer = rawdata[offset + i];
                }
            }
```

I want to make the same function, when I remove unsafe block.
How to remove the unsafe block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Marshal.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_Copy_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_IntPtr_System_Int32_)

```
Marshal.Copy(rawdata, offset, btmdata.Scan0, height * width);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was at 0 votes - it's literally in the examples for BitmapData on msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata?view=netframework-4.8#examples